# Vuex store dynamically registerModule is not reactive to template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am registering new module to existing **Vuex.Store** instance with registerModule but the newly registered module if there is any state change is not reflecting to the mappedGetters in the Vue component, is it the write way to register dynamic modules?

```
store.registerModule('newModule', {
  state: {
    name: 'Baz'
  },
  mutations: {
    setName(state, name) {
      state.name = name
    }
  },
 getters:{
   getName(state){
     return state.name
  }
}
})
```